# Is there a way to use Java Collections with extended class types?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, collections

I want to create an interface that, beyond other method signatures, will have a signature of this type:

```
Set<Instruction> parse(String rawData);
```

And in classes implementing the interface, I want to do as an implementation:

```
 Set<Instruction> parse(String rawData){
   //Do work.
   //return an object of type HashSet<DerivedInstruction>.
 }
```

Where `DerivedInstruction` extends the `Instruction` abstract class.
(Instruction could also be an interface, alternatively).

My point is not on the Collection type (I know HashSet implements Set), but on generic types.
By searching on it, I found that both `Set<Instruction>` and `HashSet<SpecificInstruction>` 
extend the `Object` type, and are not related via inheritance (at least not directly). Therefore, I can not upcast `HashSet<SpecificInstruction>`  on returning type. Any ideas on how to do this?
Thank you.

Comment: why not create an object of type `HashSet<Instruction>` instead?

Comment: I could, my focus was not on this, but on the generic type. Thanks for looking at it! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's an example how you could relax the type constraints on your `parse` methods:

```
Set<? extends Instruction> parse(String rawData) {
    //....
}
```

The full example:

```
interface Instruction {}
class DerivedInstruction implements Instruction {}

Set<? extends Instruction> parse(String rawData){
    return new HashSet<DerivedInstruction>();
}
```

Comment: Very nice and simple explanation and it works greatly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> Therefore, I can not upcast HashSet on returning type. Any ideas on
>   how to do this? Thank you.

Then you need to use the means of a bounded wildcard: `Set<? extends Instruction>` . The `?` stands for an unknown type which is in fact a subtype of `Instruction` or type of `Instruction` itself. We say that `Instruction` is the upper bound of the wildcard.

```
Set<? extends Instruction> parse(String rawData){
   //Do work.
   //return an object of type HashSet<DerivedInstruction>.
 }
```

Read about this [**more here.**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html)

Comment: Thank you Sage, I wish I could choose both answers as best.